# RESULTADO NO ESPERADO al hacer consulta SQL (POSTGRESQL 9.5) con BETWEEN - en java Netbeans

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, select, netbeans-8.2

Tengo una las siguientes tablas en mi base de datos en PostgreSQL

1. usuario : la cual contiene usuario, contraseña y tipo de usuario
2. accesos : contiene código de accesos , y nombre del acceso
3. usuario_acceso: contiene el código de acceso , y código de usuario para enlazar a que lugares tiene acceso el usuario.

```
CREATE TABLE public.usuario
(
  cod_usuario integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('usuario_cod_usuario_seq'::regclass),
  nombre character(25),
  contrasenia character(25),
  tipo_usuario smallint,
  CONSTRAINT pk_usuario PRIMARY KEY (cod_usuario),
  CONSTRAINT fk_tipo_usuario FOREIGN KEY (tipo_usuario)
      REFERENCES public.tipo_usuario (cod_tipo_usuario) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT unico_nombre_usuario UNIQUE (nombre)
)

CREATE TABLE public.accesos
(
  cod_acceso character varying(25) NOT NULL,
  nombre character(25),
  nombre_boton character varying(25),
  CONSTRAINT pk_acceso PRIMARY KEY (cod_acceso)
)

CREATE TABLE public.usuario_acceso
(
  cod_usuario_acceso bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('usuario_acceso_cod_usuario_acceso_seq'::regclass),
  cod_usuario integer,
  cod_acceso character varying(25),
  CONSTRAINT pk_usuario_accesos PRIMARY KEY (cod_usuario_acceso),
  CONSTRAINT fk_acceso FOREIGN KEY (cod_acceso)
      REFERENCES public.accesos (cod_acceso) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_usuario FOREIGN KEY (cod_usuario)
      REFERENCES public.usuario (cod_usuario) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

lo que ocurre es que al hacer la siguiente consulta en el query del mismo postgresql si funciona y sale lo que necesito :

```
SELECT ua.cod_acceso
FROM usuario_acceso ua,accesos a
where ua.cod_usuario=2 AND ua.cod_acceso=a.cod_acceso AND (ua.cod_acceso BETWEEN '1.2' AND '1.68') ORDER BY a.cod_acceso ASC;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando hago exactamente la misma consulta en java netbeans 8.2 de la siguiente manera:

el resultado es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me está mandando

```
1.2

.

1.219
```

se traga el del centro
como notaran necesito la respuesta que me da el postgresql. 
tengo que aclarar que el código de acceso está character varying.

he intentado lo siguiente

1. `ua.cod_acceso>='1.2' and ua.cod_acceso<='1.68'`
2. `ua.cod_acceso like'1.2%' and like '1.68%'`

Comment: Te estás conectando a la misma base de datos?

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras si señor, me estoy conectando a la misma base de datos. alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Por favor, [no publiques código en imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/21). Tampoco la salida en consola. Lo apropiado es publicar el texto como tal. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que ya se cuál es el problema:

Llamas a `rs.next()` en el while (esto está bien), y lo imprimes

Llamas a `rs.next()` dentro del System.out.println() (no está bien, porque no lo imprimes)

Ya viste dónde está el error?

Saludos!

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero de echo al principio no estaba, porque me di cuenta fue haciendo un Debbug, para estudiar paso a paso. y lo puse para que se viera, el resultado para poderles mostrar mejor

Comment: Es la única razón que veo por la que tendría ese comportamiento "extraño". Si ya probaste quitar el `rs.next()` de adentro del `System.out.println()` y aún no te muestra el resultado deseado, y dices que te estás conectando a la misma base de datos, me quedo sin opciones.

Comment: @YELS, te recomiendo que incluyes el código que usas realmente ya que comentas que no es tal como lo has compartido. Además, trata de agregar siempre el código como texto. Saludos.

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras disculpame Antonio reconozco mi error , cuando todos me dijieron que pusiera el codigo real , ya que en el proceso que hago, lo hacia diferente pero igual y no crei que ese fuera el problema,  y el ciclo con el while lo hice para ver que estaba pasando mostrandoles de manera mas sencilla pero concidencialmente paso lo mismo. en el otro tenia esto:if (rs.next() && consulta_cod_acceso==true) {
                        usuario_acceso=rs.getString(1);
                    } asi que claro tenias razon . Muchas Gracias y perdon la ignorancia a Todos. un saludo

Comment: No pasa nada, afortunadamente se solucionó tu problema, que es lo importante. Saludos! :-)